# Исключение 0xC0000005 в С++ при попытке сравнить соседние элементы матрицы

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N, M, j, q, l, count = 1, m, arg1 = 1, arg2 = 1;
    cout << "Vvedite kol-vo strok massiva: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Vvedite kol-vo stolbtsov massiva: ";
    cin >> M;
    m = M - 1;

    double** A = new double *[N]; // создание массива A
    for (int f = 0; f < N; f++)
    {
        A[f] = new double[M];
    }

    double x;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) // заполнение массива A рандомными числами
{
    for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        A[i][j] = rand() % 100 * 0.1;
        A[i][j] < 5 ? A[i][j] = 0 : A[i][j] = 1;
    }
}

for (int p = 0; p < N; p++) // вывод элементов массива A[N][M]
{
    cout << endl;
    for (q = 0; q < M; q++)
    {
        cout << "  " << A[p][q];
    }
}

for (int k = 0; k <= N; k++)
{
    for (l = 0; l <= m; l++)
    {
        if ((A[k][l]) == (A[k][l + 1]))
        {
            arg1 > arg2 ? arg2 = arg1 : arg1 = 1;
            count = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
            arg1 = count;
        }
    }
}
cout << endl << arg2;
cout << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Почему у вас в первых двух циклах сравнения `< N` и `< M`, а в третьем внезапно `<= N` и `<= m`?

Comment: И да, заводить две одинаковые переменные, отличающиеся лишь регистром `M` и `m` — это ОЧЕНЬ плохая идея

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Сам не понял, с чего вдруг поставил <=. Совет учту

Comment: Во внешних циклах переменная цикла объявлена локально на месте, а во внутренних - почему-то обязательно в самом начале функции. Во всех циклах повторяется этот паттерн. Что за странная манера и чем она вызвана? Также способ использования оператора `?:`  - не ошибка, но странно.

Comment: @Ant После работы с циклами подумал, что множественная инициализация одной переменной в рамках цикла не есть хорошо. А тернарную операцию выполнил вместо if, потому как занимает меньше места